# Problem generating repeated Bootstrap grid rows and columns with XSLT

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xslt

I am using XSLT to generate rows, columns, and content from a config file. I have my config rows/columns/content setup but can't figure out how to make the XSLT repeat the rows and columns to match my expected HTML output. It's only pulling the first instance of each Row/Col/Box. I know there are parameters to pass to make it repeat properly, but I don't understand how to use them properly.

**XSLT file:**

```
<xsl:template match="/XmlPages">
    <xsl:for-each select="/XmlPages/Page[@RouteUrl=$RouteUrl]">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="Row">      
    <div class="row content-row">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Col" />
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Col">
    <div class="col-{@colSize} content-col">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Box" />
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Box">      
    <div class="content-box {@boxBg}-bg" data-url="{@fileUrl}"></div>
</xsl:template>
```

**Config file:**

```
<Page Name="testPage" RouteUrl="/testPage">
    <Row>
        <Col colSize="3">
            <Row>
                <Col colSize="12">
                    <Box boxBg="clear" fileUrl="/content/test-1.html"></Box>
                </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Col colSize="12">
                    <Box fileUrl="/content/test-2.html"></Box>
                </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Col colSize="12">
                    <Box fileUrl="/content/test-3.html"></Box>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </Col>
        <Col colSize="9">
            <Row>
                <Col colSize="9">
                    <Box fileUrl="/content/test-4.html"></Box>
                </Col>
                <Col colSize="3">
                    <Row>
                        <Col colSize="12">
                            <Box boxBg="color" fileUrl="/content/test-5.html"></Box>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                        <Col colSize="12">
                            <Box boxBg="color" fileUrl="/content/test-6.html"></Box>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Col colSize="12">
                    <Box fileUrl="/content/test-7.html"></Box>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </Col>
    </Row>
</Page>
```

**Desired HTML result:**

```
<div class="row content-row">
    <div class="col-3 content-col">
        <div class="row content-row">
            <div class="col-12 content-col">
                <div class="content-box clear-bg">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row content-row">
            <div class="col-12 content-col">
                <div class="content-box">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row content-row">
            <div class="col-12 content-col">
                <div class="content-box">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-9 content-col">
        <div class="row content-row">
            <div class="col-9 content-col">
                <div class="content-box">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 content-col">
                <div class="row content-row">
                    <div class="col-12 content-col">
                        <div class="content-box color-bg">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row content-row">
                    <div class="col-12 content-col">
                        <div class="content-box color-bg">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>              
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row content-row">
            <div class="col-12 content-col">
                <div class="content-box">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot that your `Col` elements can also have `Row` children.
So change

```
<xsl:template match="Col">
  <div class="col-{@colSize} content-col">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Box" />
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

to

```
<xsl:template match="Col">
  <div class="col-{@colSize} content-col">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Row|Box" />
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

That should do the trick.
Or create a new template if the output should differ.

Comment: Awesome, will that catch them when they repeat nested as well? It looked like my initial template was only applying to the first Row/Col/Box that it saw.

Comment: As you defined your templates: Yes. I checked your example given and it worked well. If a problem occurs, you can try to change the `<xsl:template match="Row">` template to contain `<xsl:apply-templates select="Col|Row" />`.

Comment: Added the Row|Box and Col|Row changes and that fixed it for me. Thanks!